Strange timing and order of prints to log
I ran the following program through a Slurm job:
import datetime

print(f'Program started at {datetime.datetime.now()}.')

# More imports here.

print(f'Modules finished loading at {datetime.datetime.now()}.')

seed_everything(7253, workers=True)

seed_everything is defind at PyTorch Lightning and prints using the logging module.
The program produced the following log file:
[rank: 0] Seed set to 7253
Program started at 2024-08-15 16:20:52.034715.
Modules finished loading at 2024-08-15 16:21:01.970554.

All lines got printed to the log file at around the same time, at 16:21:04.
Why wasn't the "Program started" line printed at 16:20:52, when print was called?
And how did the "Seed set" line manage to get printed first?

Are you redirecting to a file or writing to the terminal?

stdout is fully buffered when not connected to a terminal. The Seed set message was probably printed to stderr, which is unbuffered.

@Barmar All of those get printed to stdout. I guess the log file is updated from the terminal of the node that runs the job.

But what is stdout connected to? A terminal or a pipe/file?

If stdout is going into the log file, it's probably connected to a pipe, so the output is buffered.

@Barmar I'm not sure how Slurm implements it. But yes, my hunch also says that it is buffered. It probably waits to gather more lines before performing an expensive IO operation. But why isn't the order preserved?

Since stderr is not buffered, it gets written to the file immediately. Buffered output is written when the buffer is flushed, which is probably when the script exits.

@Barmar But nothing is printed to stderr.

I'm assuming the Seed set message is written to stderr. And both stdout and stderr are being written to the log file.

@Barmar I understand your point if it was true. However, it is not printed to stderr. Could it be explained by it being printed using the logging module (maybe this module is unbuffered)?

Yes, that's also possible. The logging module writes to the file immediately, while stdout is written to the log file when it's flushed.

Alright then. You may write it as an answer, and I would mark it as the accepted answer.

The logging module writes to the log file immediately. Since PyTorch is using the logging module for its messages, these are written at the time they're logged.
On the other hand, when standard output of the script is piped to Slurm, this output is fully buffered. Slurm will only write it to the log file when the buffer is flushed. If the script only produces a small amount of output, this won't happen until the script exits.
On Linux you may be able to use the unbuffer command to run the script from Slurm. This redirects the script's output through a pty, so it will be line-buffered instead of fully-buffered.
